# Hiding TextBox Control with Id value from database

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

Is it okay to hide `Textbox` control with value for example `id` from database and use it for updating or deleting row with this `id` in winforms or wpf applications?

I know it is okay in Web/Internet Applications using `<html>` `hidden` field but i think in winforms/wpf it is not a good practice.

Comment: Does it makes a difference to have a invisible textbox over no textbox at all  !!!

Comment: I wouldn't use a textbox or any ui element for that matter to do it. Unlike web applications, you can keep local variables on the form to hold whatever data that doesn't need to be displayed to the customer.

Comment: No its not a good practice to use a UI component if you don't even need to show it to user, use local variable to store **id** for the current record.

Comment: As you use WPF you should think MVVM way. Id is just a value in Model, not passed to View, even nor View Model.

Comment: Thanks to you answers i think that's what will i do.

Comment: But i think there are times you need to store value in hidden control.